# Что означает статус WONTFIX в багтрекере?

Tags: bitbucket

В bitbucket.org увидел у некоторых issue статус wontfix. Что это за статус?

Comment: will not fix (не будет исправляться)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> WONTFIX - The problem described is a bug which will never be fixed

(взято с https://en.opensuse.org/Bug_Status_WONTFIX)

Это статус для ошибок, которые признаны ошибками, но которые не будут исправляться, в виду различных причин (к примеру, излишней сложности исправления, нецелесообразности и т.п.)